# Can you get a list of YouTube channels to which a user is a subscriber?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm very new to YouTube Data API and not sure if it's possible to get a list o channels to which a logged in user is a subscriber?

I see that it is possible to get following: Using mine parameter to retrieve a list of channels that subscribe to the authenticated user's channel.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list

However, I'm curious to see the subs of a user not channel.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reading (quote):

> Using mine parameter to retrieve a list of channels that subscribe to the authenticated user's channel.

is incorrect.

The request parameter `mine` of [`Subscriptions.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) API endpoint is specified as:

> [**`mine`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#mine) boolean
> This parameter can only be used in a properly [authorized request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication). Set this parameter's value to `true` to retrieve a feed of the authenticated user's subscriptions.

Therefore, querying `Subscriptions.list` with `mine=true` will return the list of channels to which you -- the authenticated user -- subscribed.

For the other way around -- i.e. for a list of channels that are subscribers of your channel -- there are two other request parameters: [`myRecentSubscribers`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#myRecentSubscribers) and [`mySubscribers`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#mySubscribers).